# Alternatives to testing HTML5 media elements

Tags: ruby-on-rails, html, testing, capybara, headless-browser

I'm testing audio tags in my Capybara tests. I'm using the poltergeist driver with PhantomJS. The problem is that the PhantomJS team resoundingly stated they have no plans to support HTML5 media elements such as `<audio>` or `<video>`. This is problematic as I need to test this audio player for a features test. Because of this, I need to replace the poltergeist driver. What driver alternatives exist? Could I by any chance run one driver for the audio tests and then run poltergeist for the other tests?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The selenium driver runs actual browsers rather than headless, and therefore supports whatever functionality real browsers support (at a slower speed than the headless drivers).

Assuming you are using the normal Capybara/RSpec configuration where you have set `Capybara.javascript_driver = :poltergeist` and are tagging your scenarios with `js: true` to indicate to use poltergeist, then you can remove the `js: true` metadata and replace it with `driver: :selenium` on the tests where you want to use audio

Comment: Ideally I would like to stick to a headless browser so I don't have to experience the browser popping-up during the test.

Comment: @jason328 Then you're limited to the features provided by the headless browsers (poltergeist/phantomjs and capybara-webkit) which are both based on QtWebkit.  Give capybara-webkit a try to see if it supports what you need - you'll want to build it with Qt 5.5.1 to have a chance of html5 audio being supported (https://github.com/thoughtbot/capybara-webkit/issues/555  would seem to indicate it does support it)

Comment: thanks for the reply. I'll do so and report back on my findings.

Comment: @jason328 and the same ability to switch drivers would still exist  - it would just be `driver: :webkit`  (or whatever you register the capybara-webkit driver as if you customize its registration)